# Is Chrooting apache/mysql/php a standard practice of securing web servers containing sensitive data?

Tags: apache-2.2, chroot

Is Chrooting apache/mysql/php a standard practice of securing web servers containing sensitive data (is it necessary)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, chrooting isn't standard practice with Apache.  I wouldn't consider it necessary either.  However, chuser and chgroup are-- you shouldn't run Apache as root.  Doing all three is common with BIND.  You should default to running with least privileges necessary with all daemons and all cases.

It's arguable that chrooting is pointless in a lot of cases as well.  Check out [Abusing a chroot jail](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Abusing_chroot).

Comment: Very informative post, though it seems to desire as a premise the contained processes and users can chroot themselves\have root priveledges. Which from the comments I understand is avoidadble in a properly setup chroot..

Comment: I agree with your point.

Answer (score -1):

Poor man's PHP environment chroot: http://www.smallbulb.net/2013/303-chroot-php

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please read our [faq] in particular [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion).